# Static file, stylesheet with Node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, sockets, express

I'm new to Nodejs and I'm having troubles to make my stylesheet (and js files) works with my Node.js server. I tried many things but nothing worked. Could you help me please ?
My stylesheet is in a "public" folder.

```
Server-side : 
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');

var app = express();
// Chargement du fichier index.html affiché au client
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
    });
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Chargement de socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket, pseudo) {
    // Quand on client se connecte, on lui envoie un message
    socket.emit('message', 'Vous êtes bien connecté !');
    // On signale aux autres clients qu'il y a un nouveau venu
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', 'Un autre client vient de se connecter ! ');

    // Dès qu'on nous donne un pseudo, on le stocke en variable de session
    socket.on('petit_nouveau', function(pseudo) {
        socket.set('pseudo', pseudo);
    });

    // Dès qu'on reçoit un "message" (clic sur le bouton), on le note dans la console
    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        // On récupère le pseudo de celui qui a cliqué dans les variables de session
        socket.get('pseudo', function (error, pseudo) {
            console.log(pseudo + ' me parle ! Il me dit : ' + message);
        });
    }); 
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Client-side :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chat par navigateur</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/stylesheet.css">
  <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" /> -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SALUTATIONS</h1>
    <p><input type="button" value="Parler au serveur" id="poke" /></p>

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script> -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            alert('Le serveur a un message pour vous : ' + message);
        })

        $('#poke').click(function () {
            alert("ok");
            socket.emit('message', 'Salut serveur, ça va ?');
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this the whole code? where is the code to serve the static files/stylesheets?

Comment: Yes it's the whole code. Isn't "app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));" ? Or maybe I missed something..

Comment: yes i didn't notice that line of code, does express logs anything when you attempt browsing the localhost url ?

Comment: Hum I just have this in the console : " info  - socket.io started
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized LxFKCDd3_g8Q4P_5Qnek
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/LxFKCDd3_g8Q4P_5Qnek
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client LxFKCDd3_g8Q4P_5Qnek
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"message","args":["Vous êtes bien conne
cté !"]}
   debug - broadcasting packet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Express 3.x, try this:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('/index.html');
});
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

/* Your socket event handlers are here.*/

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I tried but it's now written "Cannot GET /" on the localhost page

Comment: @Hornlame Update the code to add the route handler.

Comment: Now I have "GET http://localhost:8080/public/css/stylesheet.css 404 (Not Found)", I work in local and that's the matter I can't solve (because the public folder is in my hard drive)..

Comment: In `index.html`, change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/stylesheet.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesheet.css">`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked ! Now I can try Node and I will study express things later.